# Subscript out of range VBA Excel array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have this code to eliminate all anomalies in the denormlaized hierarchy table. When I try to run this macro with a hundred rows of records, maybe around 200 to 300, it works just fine. But when I try to run the macro with all of my rows, which is around 18,000 lines, it returns the "Subscript out of range" error. I'm not sure what's wrong with the code 'cause it seems to work fine with hundreds of rows. I'm using MS Excel 2010 version. Any help would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Here's my working code:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub EliminateAnomaliesDH()
Sheets("Denorm Hier").Select
Range("A1").Select
Dim iCtr As Integer
Dim arr As Variant

iCtr = 2

While Range("B" & iCtr).Value <> ""
arr = Split(Range("B" & iCtr).Value, "[")
arr = Split(arr(1), "]")

Select Case arr(0)
    Case "L1"
        Range("F" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L2"
        Range("H" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L3"
        Range("J" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L4"
        Range("L" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L5"
        Range("N" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L6"
        Range("P" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L7"
        Range("R" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L8"
        Range("T" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L9"
        Range("V" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L10"
        Range("X" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L11"
        Range("Z" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
    Case "L12"
        Range("AB" & iCtr & ":AB" & iCtr & "").Value = ""
End Select

iCtr = iCtr + 1
Wend

Sheets("Instructions").Select
MsgBox "Successfully removed all anomalies of the Denormalized hierarchy Table"
End Sub
```

Comment: Check whether you have sheet "Denorm Hier" at a right place/location .

Comment: @Charles_Stevens yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you have not mentioned the line where you are getting an error, it is quite obvious. The error is most probably on the line

```
arr = Split(arr(1), "]")
```

And the reason is very simple. Because the cell doesn't have "[" so after split there is no `ar(1)`.

Here is a very simple way to reproduce the error.

```
Sub sample()
    Dim sString As String
    Dim myar

    sString = "Blah Blah"

    myar = Split(sString, "]")

    myar = Split(myar(1), "[") '<~~ Error here

    Debug.Print myar(0)
End Sub
```

To ensure that you don't get the error, use `INSTR()` to check if `[` or `]` exists and then split it.

For example

```
    If InStr(1, sString, "]") Then
        myar = Split(sString, "]")
    End If
```

**Followup from comments**

I rewrote your code. Is this what you are trying? Please note that I have not tested it so let me know if you get any errors. I have commented the code on the relevant parts as well.

```
Sub EliminateAnomaliesDH()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long
    Dim tempString As String, sString As String

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Denorm Hier")

    With ws
        '~~> Get the last row which has data in Col B
        lRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '~~> Loop through cells in column B
        For i = 2 To lRow
            sString = .Range("B" & i).Value

            '~~> Check if the cell has both "[" and "]"
            If InStr(1, sString, "[") And InStr(1, sString, "]") Then
                tempString = Split(.Range("B" & i).Value, "[")(1)
                tempString = Split(tempString, "]")(0)

                '~~> This required so that we do an exact match
                '~~> For example, "  l1", "  l1   ", "   L1" etc
                '~~> becomes "L1"
                tempString = UCase(Trim(tempString))

                Select Case tempString
                    Case "L1": .Range("F" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L2": .Range("H" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L3": .Range("J" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L4": .Range("L" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L5": .Range("N" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L6": .Range("P" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L7": .Range("R" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L8": .Range("T" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L9": .Range("V" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L10": .Range("X" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L11": .Range("Z" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                    Case "L12": .Range("AB" & i & ":AB" & i & "").ClearContents
                End Select
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    MsgBox "Successfully removed all anomalies of the Denormalized hierarchy Table"
End Sub
```

Comment: `If InStr(1, arr, "]") Then
myar = Split(arr, "]")
End If`

Is this correct?

Comment: No. Not exactly. :) Let me see if i can update the above post with a complete example

Comment: @user3175963: Can you give me an example string and what are you trying to extract from it? Are you trying to extract what is between `[]`?

Comment: actually im trying to extract from the Denorm Hier sheet. columns from A to AB

Comment: @user3175963: Yes I got that but what are you extracting from the cell? something like "L1" from `Blah Blah [L1] Blah Blah`

Comment: @user3175963: refresh the page. I have updated my post. I think that is what you are trying to do... See the `Followup from comments` in the above post.